# Insert a button into a specific data grid view column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Can I put the button wherever the row I wanted? For example, I want to put the button in row[2], so the button will be appear in that row at every columns.

I tried to made something like this to made the button in the right, but I failed :

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        btn.HeaderText = "Delete";
        btn.Text = "   ";
        btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.ColumnCount = 5; 

        tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Header1";
        tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Header2";
        tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Header3";
        tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Header4";
        tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.Columns.Add(btn);
```

And this is for the looping data :

```
tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = (i + 1);
            tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = Value1;
            tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = Value2;
            tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = Value3;
            DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.Rows.Add(btn);

            i++;
```

But this doesn't work. I thought if I empty one columns, the button will automatically be there. I'm sorry, I'm still beginner.

Comment: It would make it easier to help if you also described *why* you want to that.

Comment: Rows.Add adds a row not a DataGridViewButtonColumn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use gridView.Columns.Insert() instead of gridView.Rows.Add(). Please take a look:

```
        int columnIndex = 4;

        if (tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.Columns["Delete"] == null)
        {
            tbl_incomingrawmaterialform.Columns.Insert(columnIndex, btn);
        }
```

Happy coding!